# Shortcode to display all the post from a category in a page

Tags: categories, shortcode

I have 10 category, and when i select a category in the sidebar il list all the post from that category.... FINE, beautiful

Now, i like a page, with some text and photos and then after that content, i like to have all the post from a category listed, just like the category view...

Is there a plugin or a short code that just do that ?

Comment: search the plugins for 'list category posts' http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=list+category+posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
<?php
function list_post(){

    //or you can use the cat id here, check the codex for WP_Query
    $q = new WP_Query(array('category_name' => '<cat slug here>'));
    if($q->have_posts()):
        while($q->have_posts()):the_post();
            the_title();
        endwhile;
    else:
        echo "No posts found!";
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
}

add_shortcode('list_post', 'list_post');
?>
```

Comment: Does this work outside the loop?

Comment: Probably won't. But you can try using the id or slug directly.